# How can I parse out and execute JavaScript using getJSON in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code:

```
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            /******* Load HTML *******/
             var jsonp_url = "http://184.72.244.64/test.fwx?callback=?";         
            $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
              $('#DivTagToInsertTheHTML').html(data.html);
            });
        });
    }
```

I would like to deliver a considerable amount of JavaScript through to the client browser using this function. The reason I need to use this is that I need to retrieve it from an outside server which breaks the "same origin policy".

So when I get the JavaScript inside JSON, how do I parse it out and execute it? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

ok,

try this:

use jquery ajax call with crossDomain: true

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or use xDomainRequest (for IE) and XMLHttpRequest (specific objects for cross domain requests)

you should, if you can, aware the server with CORS on processing request with:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
if ($this->getRequestMethod() == 'OPTIONS')
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with');
    exit(0);
}
```

here is a good post:

http://tpeczek.blogspot.pt/2010/09/httphandler-with-cross-origin-resource.html

Comment: How do I execute the JavaScript after I get it?

Comment: i'm not sure if I understand right what you want... but for execute a JS function when you receive the server response if you use jquery ajax it can be like this:

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function (data) { /*evaluate the data object, i dont know how it is returned, and then */ $('#DivTagToInsertTheHTML').html(data.html); }
})

Answer (score 0):

You use the javascript eval function. Just keep in mind, this is a security risk. Cross domain security is in place for a reason. Why do you need to run javascript in real time?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP